# Add/remove tab in TabbedPage bar and change app:tabMode programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

In Xamarin, I'm having a TabbedPage which sometimes should be displayed and sometimes not.

```
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding5" IsEnabled="False">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 5"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I tried to disable it at default and enable it like this:

```
if(Application.Current.Properties["txt_voeding5"].ToString() != "")
{
    tab_Voeding5.IsEnabled = true;
    tab_Voeding5.Title = Application.Current.Properties["txt_voeding5"].ToString();
}
```

However, this only disables and enables the title of the tabbed page in the navigation bar, but I want it completely removed/added. How do I do this?

Also, in `Tabbar.axml` I want `app:tabMode="scrollable"` only at page A. I want it to be default like `app:tabMode="fixed"`. How do I change `app:tabMode` programmatically in the page's CS file?

**EDIT:**

**Xaml file**

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TimeToSport.Views.VoedingPage"
         Title="Voeding">

<!-- Voeding 1 -->
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding1">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 1"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

<!-- Voeding 2 -->
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding2">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 2"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

<!-- Voeding 3 -->
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding3">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 3"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

<!-- Voeding 4 -->
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding4">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 4"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>

<!-- Voeding 5 -->
<ContentPage x:Name="tab_Voeding5" IsEnabled="False">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Voeding pagina 5"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: you can check out this https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138302/how-do-i-hide-the-tabs-of-tabbedpage-when-clicking-a-nested-navigationpage

Comment: I'm not trying to figure it out, but it's kinda hard..

Comment: Ohk tomorrow I'll create demo application of it to help u. You edit your questions & add tab xaml file

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I didn't try than by thinking that you might have different context of doing it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean?